# Excel macro call does not work from timer, but does from another macro

Tags: excel, vba, timer, call

I am trying to get excel to run an update every XX seconds.

```
Sub StartTesting() 
       Call RunAll_ISP   'this call works 
End Sub

Sub macro_timer() 'This sub schedules next run in XX seconds.
    Dim ScanInterval
    ScanInterval = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuration").Range("B5").Value, "hh:mm:ss")
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(ScanInterval), "RunAll_ISP", Schedule:=True  ' !this macro call throws error!
End Sub
```

If I run **Start_testing** macro, call works.
If I run **macro_timer** macro, it waits desired number of seconds, and then throwsthis error:

> Cannot run the macro "C:\location_of_file\filename.xlsm'!RunAll_ISP'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled

The settings for macros in the Trust center are set to "Enable VBA macros"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the `RunAll_ISP` procedure located? Is it in a standard module? Is it declared `Public`?

Comment: All subs are in ThisWorkbook. Tried Public - made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem cannot be reproduced. This simple Example works.
So since your procedure `StartTesting` worked that means macros are definitely enabled, so the only option left is that your macro `RunAll_ISP` does not exist (or wrongly named).

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub RunAll_ISP()
    MsgBox "I run"
End Sub


Public Sub CreateTimer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "RunAll_ISP", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: I started with the blank book, and added the code above to it. However I got exactly the same result. Here is a screenshot: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/SQJXvL4uD713Y9MU7). BTW I'm using Office 365

Comment: And here is the screenshot when running the RunAll_ISP : [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Yz7nBDMnrTrpMAHh8)

Comment: @Eki because you put the code in `ThisWorkbook` and not into a `Module`! Als I asked in my first comment the code needs to be inserted into a standard (non class) module. So add a module and move the code there and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much ! adding the module and having code there did work. I need to read about it more. for anyone with the same issue, here is a screenshot how it supposed to look like: [link](https://photos.app.goo.gl/SZ2ZZn2yiC4AVkib8)